# segmentation error depending on the order of my declarations in c++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am new to c++. Doing it for the past 9 months or so and didn't learn it by the books. I always learnt whatever I just tried to accomplish. This might have ended in me doing some sloppy codes, so I am happy if you guys would suggest advices for a more proper code, but mainly solve the issue at hand.

What my code does: It's supposed to create a structure that makes it easy for me find and use radii in two dimensions x[-50;50] y[-50;50] but only for integers. My declared structure for this task is indexed by "sqared radius" (max: 5000) and filled with:

- an index (for later use of the array "radidx")
- the amount of positions with the same radius
- its true radius (sqrt)
- the x and y position of each coordinate

Just so you know what's going on in my code.

Now the problem goes like this: If I declare the array "radidx" before the structure declaration I end up with my solution. But if I declare it after the structure, I get a segmentation error because entries in the structure seem to go terribly wrong.

As far as I know and a friend confirmed this. The order of declarations on top of my code - long before any of these declarations is used - shouldn't make a difference, so this must be because some sloppy coding of myself. I would like to improve on this in order to avoid similar issues in future codes and when putting this code here into use. Neither of us could figure out where and what went wrong.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <list>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

// int radidx[1030] = {0}; // Here it does work.
struct radii { int idx; int a=0; double r; int x[32]; int y[32]; };
radii radius[5000];
int radidx[1030] = {0}; // Here it doesn't work.

void rad_corr_init() {
    int count [5001];
    for (int i=0;i<5001;i++) count[i]=0;
/// Helper Function
    /// count amount of positions with the same radius
    for (int i=-50;i<51;i++)
    for (int j=-50;j<51;j++)
    count[i*i+j*j]++;
    /// sort collected radii and exclude radii that don't exist so one can run a for-loop of an radius interval
    int ik=0;
    for (int i=1;i<5001;i++)
    if(count[i]) {radidx[ik]=i; ik++;}

    for (int i=-50;i<51;i++) // This is put here for testing
    for (int j=-50;j<51;j++) { // This is put here for testing
        int il = i*i+j*j; // This is put here for testing
        radius[il].a=0; // This is put here for testing
    } // This is put here for testing

/// Create Radius Structure
    for (int i=-50;i<51;i++)
    for (int j=-50;j<51;j++) {
        int il = i*i+j*j;
        int im = radius[il].a;
        if (!radius[il].a) radius[il].r = sqrt(il);
        radius[il].x[im] = i;
        radius[il].y[im] = j;
        radius[il].a++;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<1030;i++) {printf("%d\t%d\n",i,radidx[i]) /* This is put here for testing */ ;radius[radidx[i]].idx = i;}
}

int main() {
    FILE * result = fopen( "result.txt", "w" );
    rad_corr_init();
    for (int i=0;i<1030;i++) {
        int in = radidx[i];
        int io = radius[in].a;
        for (int j=0;j<io;j++) {
            cout << i << '\t' << in << '\t' << radius[in].r << '\t' << j << '\t' << radius[in].x[j] << '\t' << radius[in].y[j] << endl;
            fprintf(result, "%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%f\t%d\t%d\n", i, radius[in].idx, in, radius[in].r, j, radius[in].x[j], radius[in].y[j]);
        }
    }
//  system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I used the following commands for compiling (in case this is part of the issue):

```
g++ radius.cpp -std=c++11 -o ~[some name]/Desktop/run.out;time  ~[some name]/Desktop/run.out
g++ -O4 radius.cpp -std=c++11 -o ~[some name]/Desktop/run.out;time  ~[some name]/Desktop/run.out
```

Thank you guys for your help.

Comment: `for (int i=1;i<5001;i++) if(count[i]) {radidx[ik]=i; ik++;}` makes me nervous. Perhaps you've worked it out (I haven't) so `if(count[i])` is true no more than 1030 times, but if `ik` increments beyond 1029, then you're out of bounds of your `radidx` array

Comment: These things scream buffer overflow. Sanitizers (asan and ubsan) are your friends. valgrind too.

Comment: In other news, C-style arrays and global variables bad, std::vector and function parameters good. Perhaps there is value in getring a sane C++ book.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Thanks. It worked. Do you have any idea, why it did work when I changed the order of declaration? Shouldn't it also go wrong there?

Comment: @JuliaThiele Overflowing a buffer is undefined behavior,, which means exactly that. Nobody knows what's going to happen. Changing the order of code may change how things are laid on in memory, which may change how critical a buffer overflow is ..? But don't waste your time trying to understand undefined behavior. Spend your time looking for it and eliminating it.

Answer (score 4):

You have 5001 entries for `count`, but only 5000 for `radius`.  When you access `radius[50*50+50*50]` (=`radius[5000]`) you exceed the bounds of the array and overwrite whatever is in memory after `radius`.

The solution is to change the declaration to `radii radius[5001]`.